# How is it possible to get all available java script methods of the component rich:modalPanel?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have this rich:modalPanel in my xhtml page:

```
<rich:modalPanel id="submitPanel" width="100" height="100"
    style="text-align:center;margin-top:30px;">
    <h:graphicImage value="/img/ajax-loader.gif" style="border: 0;"
            height="30" width="30" />
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Now i can call it in the onclick js attribute of the component h:commandLink for example:

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="dontsave left" value="#{txt.cancel}"
        action="#{newMessageBean.cancelAction}"
        onclick="#{rich:component('submitPanel')}.show(); return true;" />
```

But how can i get all available js methods of the component rich:modalPanel? The JBoss Documentation is not a good way, so it can be possible that i use an older richfaces version, which is not documented in a suitable way.

How call i inspect these objects with all available methods on runtime? For example by using Firebug and the command "console.log(#{rich:component('submitPanel')})" or something else? What is the best way of solution?

Comment: You are not right. Go to [http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/docs](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/docs) and check RichFaces 3.3.3 section. There is good documentation. Try start with [demo](http://showcase-rf3.richfaces.org/).

Comment: SO but i have the situation in the past and would like to work with the documented methods of the rich:calendar component. And in this case, the documentation und the use object was not the same !!

Comment: In Developer Guide each component has section `JavaScript API`. For calendar component it is **Table 6.163. JavaScript API**. See [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_calendar.html)

Comment: More info about using javascrript with RichFaces is in book _Practical RichFaces, Second Edition_

Comment: YOU ARE NOT RIGHT ! Looking here: The documentation speaks in relation to the rich:calendar component from a method "getSelectedDate()" but this method doesn´t work because it doesn´t exist in this object. The right method is "getSelectedDateString()" in this case

Comment: @MaikHansen what version of RichFaces are you using? The `getSelectedDate()` method exists in RF 3.3.3.Final.

Answer (score 0):

You can call show modal panel like this:

```
<a4j:commandButton styleClass="button" value="#{msg.addNote}"
    oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('noteDetails')">
</a4j:commandButton>

<rich:modalPanel id="noteDetails" />
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:graphicImage value="/images/close.png" 
            style="cursor:pointer" onclick="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('noteDetails')" />
    </f:facet>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

---

Here is version with `onclick`:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Find Segments" immediate="true"
    ajaxSingle="true"
    oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('clientCatSearch')"
    event="onclick" reRender="clientCatSearch">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the full id of the component, e.g. `j_id352:panel`. Then you can access the component with `$('j_id352:panel').component`.

You can't use `#{rich:component('submitPanel')}` because the `#{…}` only works for server-side processing, before the page is rendered.

You should consider updating though, at least to RF 3.3.3 if you can't go to RF 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect `ModalPanel.prototype` object in Firebug.

A quick JavaScript snippet to output all members of `ModalPanel.prototype`:

```
var result = '';
for (var item in ModalPanel.prototype) {
   result += item + '\n';
}
alert(result);
```